# iOS application is not Compatible with iPhone 4/4s/5

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Today my first application is live on apple store and that is very good news for me, but there is one issue which is that my app is not Compatible with iphone 4/4s and iphone 5, why this is not Compatible with these phones? and i did not perform such as these things that my application is not Compatible whith these phones, please anyone guide me on right direction, any help will be highly appreciated, below is the Compatibility snapshot on app store:

[image]

Comment: Do you find any solutions of your question?

Answer (score 1):

In your build settings, you didn't include ARMv7/s in the list of architectures you build for. You are 64-bit only; the devices listed in your screen shot are the 64-bit devices, with 32-bit devices excluded.